# Modifying a namedtuple's constructor arguments via subclassing?

Tags: python, new-operator, super, namedtuple

I want to create a `namedtuple` which represents the individual flags in a short bitfield.  I'm trying to subclass it so that I can unpack the bitfield before the tuple is created.  However, my current attempt isn't working:

```
class Status(collections.namedtuple("Status", "started checking start_after_check checked error paused queued loaded")):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, status):
        super(cls).__new__(cls, status & 1, status & 2, status & 4, status & 8, status & 16, status & 32, status & 64, status & 128)
```

Now, my experience with `super()` is limited and my experience with `__new__` is  virtually non-existent, so I'm not quite sure what to make of the (to me) enigmatic error `TypeError: super.__new__(Status): Status is not a subtype of super`.  Googling and digging into the docs haven't yielded anything enlightening.

Help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You almost had it :-)  There are just two little corrections:

1. The *new* method needs a *return* statement
2. The *super* call should have two arguments, *cls* and *Status*

The resulting code looks like this:

```
import collections

class Status(collections.namedtuple("Status", "started checking start_after_check checked error paused queued loaded")):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, status):
        return super(cls, Status).__new__(cls, status & 1, status & 2, status & 4, status & 8, status & 16, status & 32, status & 64, status & 128)
```

It runs cleanly, just like you had expected:

```
>>> print Status(47)
Status(started=1, checking=2, start_after_check=4, checked=8, error=0, paused=32, queued=0, loaded=0)
```

Comment: Should be `super(Status, cls)`!

Answer (score 10):

I'd avoid `super` unless you're explicitly catering to multiple inheritance (hopefully not the case here;-).  Just do something like...:

```
def __new__(cls, status):
    return cls.__bases__[0].__new__(cls,
                                    status & 1, status & 2, status & 4,
                                    status & 8, status & 16, status & 32,
                                    status & 64, status & 128)
```

Comment: you could also reduce code duplication by using this: `return cls.__bases__[0].__new__(cls, *(status & (1 << x) for x in range(0, 8)))`